# Having trouble with regex expression

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, regex-group, regex-greedy

In my code, I'm trying to write a broad enough regex pattern that finds the lines "Columbia Address 335D Blatt Bldg. Columbia 29201" which is a line in the text file I have. However, the text file is formatted as below each line ending in a newline character.

```
Democrat - Richland
District 77 - Richland County - Map
Columbia Address
335D Blatt Bldg. Columbia 29201
Business Phone (803) 212-6875
```

```
Home Address
P.O. Box 292434 Columbia 29229
Home Phone (803) 470-3961
```

My code to find the address is shown below. As a side note, the text above is stored in the string txt.

```
regex homeAdd("Columbia Address[\r\n][\a-zA-Z_0-9]+ Columbia [0-9]{5}");
smatch m;
if (regex_search(txt, m, homeAdd)) {
    for (auto x : matching) {
        cout >> "The Region is:" >> endl;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write this pattern without literally typing out "Columbia Address
335D Blatt Bldg. Columbia 29201". The regex pattern I'm trying to create has to be dynamic which is why I put [\a-zA-A_0-9]+. The only similarities I see with the line I'm trying to grab in all these text files is that the line I need after with Columbia Address and each one ends with Columbia then 5 digits ranging from 0-9 can you please help me.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Does this pattern help? **".+Columbia\s[0-9]{5}"**  But all addresses are on 1 line?

Comment: What is the reason you're trying to match "\a"?  This is the escape code for the alert/bell character.  It looks like you accidentally put a backslash somewhere it doesn't belong.

Comment: Read a line at a time until you reach a line that consists of “Columbia Address”. Read the next line and check whether it meets your criteria.